# Mapping String data from List

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mapping, java-17

I am new in mapping response DTO's coming from a List DTO's and I am stuck in this dilemma.

FF are the details of my Issue:

This is my flat table entity using MongoDb

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Document(collection = "booking")
public class BookingEntity  {


    @Id
    private String id;

    private List<BookingDTO> booking;

    private List<ItemDTO> item;

    private List<ShipperDetailsDTO> shipper_details;

    }
```

This is my response DTO

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ViewAllDTO  {


    private String booking_number;

    private String sender_name;

    private String item_details;


}
```

Now, what I want to happen is this.

I want a mapper delegator wherein my ViewAllDto class could get the selected data from my Booking entity class something like this:

```
 public ViewAllDTO toDTO (BookingEntity entity) {
        ViewAllDTO dto = bookingMapper.toDTO(entity);
        dto.setBooking_number(entity.getBooking_number()); // -> This is taken from the List<BookingDTO> on the Booking entity class
        dto.setSender_name(StringUtils.normalizeSpace(String.format("%s %s", entity.getFirst_name(), entity.getLast_name()))); // -> This is taken from the List<ShipperDetailsDTO> on the Booking entity class
        dto.setItem_details(
            entity.getItem_description(),
            entity.getWeight(),
            entity.getHeight(),
            entity.getLength(),
            entity.getWidth(),
            entity.getDeclared_value(),
            entity.getPackage_handling_type()); // -> This is taken from the List<ItemDTO> on the Booking entity class

        return dto;
    }
```

NOTE: the sample delegated mapper above is incorrect as you can see this produces a build error since I can't directly map string data for my ViewAllDTO from the List DTO's inside my entity class.

I wonder what could be the solution for this issue. Any insights will be sincerely and highly appreciated. Thanks.

Addendum:

BookingDTO class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BookingDTO  {


    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String booking_number;

    private String status; }
```

ItemDTO class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ItemDTO  {


    private String item_description;

    private BigDecimal weight;

    private BigDecimal height;

    private BigDecimal length;

    private BigDecimal width;

    private BigDecimal declared_value;

    private String package_handling_type;}
```

ShipperDetailsDTO class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ShipperDetailsDTO  {

    private String first_name;

    private String last_name;}
```

Sample payload I want to achive:

```
GET Method:

    {
    "booking_number": "<String>", (Booking number from BookingDTO)
     "sender_name":  "<String>", (First name + Last name from ShipperDetailsDTO)
      "item_details": "<String>" (All item details from ItemDTO)
    }
```

Comment: setItem_details method accepts only one String as a parameter. But you are passing more than one String. I think you need to concatenate all the String to one String and set it.

Comment: How do I do this? Basically, all the data's I want to extract from my class are all coming from the List Object. I am at loss as to how I could call on the selected data's I want from my entity class..:(

Comment: you can iterate the list and return as a String.

Comment: Can you provide sample input(BookingEntity) and output(ViewAllDTO) expected from the above toDTO method.

Comment: Can I see a sample code for this one? If it's possible on your end for visibility?  And further question, if I do this will be a able to call a data from the different List Dto's inside my entity class and set it to my preferred response dto?

Comment: I didnt understand your question. But check the answer i have provided and that might help to clarify your second doubt

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the response you want but I have written below sample code for reference.

```
        ViewAllDTO viewAllDTO = new ViewAllDTO();
        List<BookingDTO> booking=new ArrayList<>();
        booking.add(new BookingDTO("123","success"));
        List<ItemDTO> item= new ArrayList<>();
        item.add(new ItemDTO("new Item", new BigDecimal("1"), 
                new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("1"), new BigDecimal("1"), 
                new BigDecimal("1"),"big"));
        List<ShipperDetailsDTO> shipper_details=new ArrayList<>();
        shipper_details.add(new ShipperDetailsDTO("Shipper_First","Shipper_Last"));

        String bookingDetails = booking.stream()
                .map(x->x.getBooking_number())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        String senderDetails = shipper_details.stream()
                .map(x->x.getFirst_name()+x.getLast_name())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        String itemDetails = item.stream()
                .map(x->x.getItem_description() + " - " +
                        x.getWeight() + " - " +
                        x.getHeight()+ " - " +
                        x.getLength()+ " - " +
                        x.getWidth()+ " - " +
                        x.getDeclared_value()+ " - " +
                        x.getPackage_handling_type())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

        viewAllDTO.setBooking_number(bookingDetails);
        viewAllDTO.setItem_details(itemDetails);
        viewAllDTO.setSender_name(senderDetails);

        System.out.println(viewAllDTO);
```

So you will get out put like the below.

```
ViewAllDTO(booking_number=123, sender_name=Shipper_FirstShipper_Last, item_details=new Item - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - big)
```

Comment: Hey! I come back to say thank you to you. You have no idea how much this helps me. You save my life and my job. I love you. God Bless you, my hero. This code works for me.❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️